# Where to place buttons on a phone application

Tags: mobile-web, mobile-application

Where is the best place to put buttons on a phone application where everything is based around a google map which is always displayed, for commonly used functions such as search? ie:

top, left, bottom, right, middle??

: and why?

Comment: What sort of button? What is its purpose? What sort of phone? What sort of application? There is no correct answer to such a brief question as this, but if you can provide context and explain your actual situation then we can help answer that.

Comment: The UI is centred around a google map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since search is probably the most used function in a map application, I would follow what Google and Apple have done in their map applications - placing it at the very top.

[image: ios7 maps]

[image]

In both these applications, the search bar (and any buttons connected to the search function, such as directions) are placed at the top.
Any other buttons are placed at the bottom.

The application from Google only has two buttons, and the menu button will open a drawer menu containing the available menu options.

So this really depends on what purpose each button you wish to place is.

Comment: Nice answer thanks. Yes, best i follow what people already know!

Comment: Placing the search (and related buttons) at the top makes sense, especially if the search box provides autocomplete functionality the "dropdown" list (esp. when sorted alphabetically or by importance) makes most sense to drop downwards... and thus I almost feel that you have little choice but to put it at the top ;-)